# @RequestParam CustomMap<String, Object> map: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring-mvc

I tried to find solutions for following code snippet but in vain.

So here is my code looking for help: test.java

```
public class TestMap extends HashMap<String, Object> { 

}

@RequestMapping({ "doTest.action", "/"})
public ModelAndView doTest(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam Map<String, Object> map
        ) throws Exception {
     ...
     ...
}
```

If i replace the line:

```
@RequestParam Map<String, Object> map
```

With:

```
@RequestParam TestMap<String, Object> map
```

I catch the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [controller.UserAction]
Method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView controller.UserAction.toTest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,com.demo.tools.TestMap) throws java.lang.Exception]
Resolved arguments: 
[0] [type=org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade] [value=org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@66de04cd]
[1] [type=org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade] [value=org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade@7a0d637d]
[2] [type=java.util.LinkedHashMap] [value={}]

```
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:216)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

root cause

Any idea why ?

Thanks.

Comment: please post complete stack trace

Comment: got the same issue. any solutions?